# What is the command for starting the program right after compiling in the GNU GCC compiler?

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm looking for the command to insert in the Makefile in order to have the program start  directly after compiling. I haven't been able to find it on the GNU GCC website.

Comment: There isn't one.

Comment: The compiler does not start the program. The shell does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an `all` clause to your makefile that builds and runs the program, like in the following example:

```
all: build run

build: a.out

a.out: foo.c
    gcc foo.c -o a.out

run:
    ./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a command to the rule that builds your executable (call it `foo`):

```
foo: foo.c
    gcc whatever
    ./foo
```

Or (better) make it a separate rule, so that `make foo` builds the executable, and `make run-foo` builds it (if need be) and then runs it:

```
foo: foo.c
    ...

.PHONY: run-foo

run-foo: foo
    ./$<
```